# How to use Sql from DOS prompt

Tags: mysql, dos, prompt

Hi I have installed MySQL from oracle website, but did not get a "MySQL Command Line" option under MySQL in Programs menu.

So I looked up on this site how to execute sql queries from DOS command prompt.

I found an answer on this site that advised to type in something like: `sql root u- p-`  etc. but this does not work.

Can anyone advise me the syntax to use to go into sql from DOS, or direct me to the answer described above (I cannot locate it)

I use Windows 7 and downloaded the ODBC driver, too.

Many  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless MySQL's bin directory is in your `PATH` variable, you will need to either be in the directory, or write an absolute path to it to execute.

Try something like this (depending on your installation):

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
mysql -uroot
```

Alternatively, you could type this directly:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd/
cd wamp
cd bin
cd mysql
cd mysql5.0.51b
#################################
note use your own version of mysql, mine is 5.0.51b
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
cd bin
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
////////////////////////////////
note -p that is if u use a password
////////////////////////////////////////
```

after this line of codes you have this
welcome note telling you the server version of mysql and your connection id

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the bin directory of the program you just installed then type "mysql.exe"

Have a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) guide if you get stuck with the commands

Comment: `sqlplus` does not come with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Determine the path of your MySQL installation, and add it to `PATH` environment variable.

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\MySQL\bin
```

The above example assumes MySQL to be installed in C:\MySQL directory.

Once path is set, then you can directly execute

```
mysql -u root
```

Which logs into MySQL as root user. The `-p` flag can be used if password is required

It is required to execute `SET PATH` every time, hence you may make a batch file.